# Django Simple JWT non_field_errors":["No active account found with the given credentials]

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

With the `django rest framework` I was using `django-rest-framework-simplejwt` from [here](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt).

According to the guideline given, my `settings.py` `REST_FRAMERWORK` should look like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Now when I call the api `/api/token/` with the help of `CURL` like this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "aami", "password": "ooma"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/
```

I get the following error:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "aami", "password": "ooma"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/

And the server side the log is:

> Bad Request: /api/token/
>   [12/Apr/2019 15:01:02] "POST /api/token/ HTTP/1.1" 400 75

I followed what the guidelines mentioned but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: If the error is `no active account with the given credentials`, it seems you are not passing the correct `username` and `password`, or the `username` does not exists.

Comment: How did you create your users ? Can you show the piece of code ?

Answer (score 3):

This was happening to me. I realized I had created my users with

```
User.objects.create(username="xxx", password="yyy")
```

But in Django a special `create_user` method needs to be used. I deleted the user and changed to

```
User.objects.create_user(username="xxx", password="yyy")
```

and it worked.

Comment: What's the difference between `User.objects.create` and `User.objects.create_user`?

Comment: Django uses the special create_user method to ensure the password is hashed

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and turns out my problem was not activating the user after they have verified their emails using `is_active=True`. For more details check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/70820311/12601926

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30886855)