# How to solve error 401 unauthorized login in DRF simple jwt user login

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am creating DRF authentication APIs for Abstract Base users in my Django project and using simple JWT. The registration and email verification APIs work fine, but when I try to log in using the credentials of a valid user, I get an error 401 unauthorized access.

the custom user model in `models.py`

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True,db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True,db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def tokens(self):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(self)
        return{
            'refresh':str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token)
        }
```

Here are my `login` and `verification` views:

```py
class VerifyEmail(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    token_param_config = openapi.Parameter('token',in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Description', type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[token_param_config])
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token,settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Succesfully activated'}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here is my `login` serializer:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=255, min_length=3)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=8, write_only=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, min_length=3, read_only = True)
    tokens = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=8, read_only = True)


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'password', 'username', 'tokens']


    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
  
        user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if not user:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Invalid Credentials, try again!')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Acccount disabled, please contact admin')
        if not user.is_verified:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Email is not verified')
                
        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'tokens': user.tokens
        }
        
        return super().validate(attrs)
```

So the error raised is "Invalid credentials" meaning that details of the user don't exist, while the users are actually there when I check the database.
[image]

Anyone, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a lot of googling and headaches, I ended up reading the [Simple Jwt documentation](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#user-authentication-rule) again and as it turns out, the 401 error occurs if the user is not active. In my `models.py` above, by default, my user's `is_verified` and `is_active` are `False`. The `VerifyEmail` view changed the `is_verified` to `True` after the users verified their emails but their `is_active` remained `False` hence giving the **error 401**.
My solution was adding an `is_active=True` for when the user verifies their email:
Here is the `VerifyEmail` view in `views.py`

```py
class VerifyEmail(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = EmailVerificationSerializer

    token_param_config = openapi.Parameter('token',in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Description', type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

    @swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[token_param_config])
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.GET.get('token')
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token,settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
            user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
            if not user.is_verified:
                user.is_verified = True
                user.is_active = True           # New
                user.save()
            return Response({'email': 'Succesfully activated'}, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Activation Expired'}, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as identifier:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to exclude your login view from the project-wide authentication check that you have added in settings.py.

```
class LoginAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This gives me an error 403 Forbidden